# Can we have an Ajax Call inside Marketo Load script

Tags: javascript, jquery, marketo

Is it possible to call an Ajax from the Marketo script? Like the below given code.

I would need an ajax call as

1. I want to pass the Marketo Form values to a php file
2. then use the values to do some calculation
3. then  to display the results on the page

   ```
   <script src="//xxxxx.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
   <form id="mktoForm_1"></form>
   <script>
   MktoForms2.loadForm("//aqq-abc.marketo.com", "xxx-XXX-xxx", id1, function(form) {
       form.onSubmit(function() {

           var vals = form.vals();

           $.ajax({
                       type: "POST", 
                       url: "http://localhost:3422/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/calM/new_generate.php",
                   data: {Value1:val[0],Value2: vals[1]},
           success: function( data ) {
                       alert(data);

           },
           error:  function( err ) {alert("Some thing went wrong! Please try again with your values.");}
           });

         });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I am able to call an ajax from Marketo Script. Need to add the jQuery lib too for this. The below is the complete working snippet.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//xxxxx.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_1"></form>
<script>
MktoForms2.loadForm("//aqq-abc.marketo.com", "xxx-XXX-xxx", id1, function(form) {
    form.onSubmit(function() {

        var vals = form.vals();

        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "http://localhost:3422/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/calM/new_generate.php",
                data: {Value1:vals.Email,Value2: vals.Phone},
        success: function( data ) {
                    alert(data);

        },
        error:  function( err ) {alert("Some thing went wrong! Please try again with your values.");}
        });

      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine in principal.  Depending on what you're trying to do onValidate may be a better callback event to use.

Comment: Can you please give me more details on how to use callback event onValidate..
I have tried my code I have placed above, but it doesn't go to the next php file.
My Requirement is : On click of Marketo Submit, form values to be used for calculation and results displayed on the same page.

Comment: Can you please give me a code snippet of Marketo Script using ajax.

Comment: I still have ISSUE using AJAX.---->if ajax call is included then any statements from ajax call are not executed.---->if ajax call is removed then all statement gets executed. ======>What is that I am missing here? ======>Or is there any other option that would take me to a php file where I can execute the php functions on Marketo Submit?